# Side view is not in orthographic view?

Tags: 3d-view, interface, 2d, object-mode, orthographic

Before when I went into side view it would automatically put it in orthographic view but now it isn't. How do I fix this?[image: Side view]

Answer (score 2):

You can press <kbd>Numpad 5</kbd> shortcut for toggling Between Orthographic and Perspective.

[image: Icon shows that you are in Perspective]

You can click on the circled icon to toggle the view type as well.

You are looking for the icon to look like below:

[image: Example of Ortho Icon]

If it still isn't automatic try the user preferences under *Edit > Preferences*

[image: Example 2]

Make sure that this is set up as so.

You can then save your pref using the sandwich menu (the three lines in the bottom left corner)

Comment: That should be Numpad 5 shouldn't it? numpad 0 is camera view.

Comment: Aye, yes you are correct! My bad, I was thinking on another subject. I will make the appropriate edits. Thanks for making me aware of this.